# writing simple python function

Tags: python

u am  starting to learn python, and  want to get some experience with functions , for instance  i have wrote following simple code  in python

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    elif n > 2:
        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)

    for n in range(1, 4):
        print(n,", ",fibonacci(n))
```

but when i have run this code, i am getting just  this  line

```
C:\Users\Dato\Desktop\Python_codes\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Dato/Desktop/Python_codes/fibonacci.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

so why  does not it shows me result?

Comment: Indenting is important in Python. Your `for` loop is inside the function.

Comment: your for loop is inside your function definition.  If you unindent the last 2 lines it should work.

Comment: how to indicate that function is finished?

Comment: @datodatuashvili `return` finishes the function here.

Comment: then why is  loop inside function?

Comment: Please work through one or two tutorials on writing functions.
You're asking questions that are outside Stack Overflow's posting guidelines, as they are easily found in such on-line resources.

Comment: Quick overview of [python indentation](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/statement-indentation-comments#indentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're having is that you never call the function `fibonacci`.

I think you've got your tabbing off,

```
    for n in range(1, 4):
        print(n,", ",fibonacci(n))
```

shouldn't be inside the function.

Try this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    elif n > 2:
        return fibonacci(n-1)+fibonacci(n-2)

for n in range(1, 4):
    print(n,", ",fibonacci(n))
```

Comment: wait what is different i  can't guess

Comment: The way the function is written in the question, `for n in range(1, 4): print(n,", ",fibonacci(n))` is inside the function and therefore the function never gets called

Answer (score 1):

you miss the callign part. 
You just defined a function.

Now, you need to call it.

add

```
fibonacci(42)
```

at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure on how you call the function, could you provide more information about that?

```
import random

any_number = randint()
print(fibonachi(any_number))
```

Comment: so i would  like to understand what is meaning of indention here

Comment: sorry not sure i understand the question.